# How can I add an animation curve to an object with no animations?

Tags: unity, animation

I want to scale text in different ways over time. I figured the best way to do this would be an animation curve. It turns out I need an actual animation clip just to create this curve.

My question is, is there a way to create and use an animation curve, or something like it, without making a redundant animation for this object? If not, is there anyway to create empty animation clips from the Unity editor?

Importing empty animations from third party applications into Unity just to use the animation curves seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create an [AnimationCurve](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html), sample it overtime and use the value to modify an object parameter, such as scale:

```
public AnimationCurve myCurve; //let's say you edit from inspector, but you can built at runtime if you prefer

float t;
void Update()
{
  t+= Time.deltaTime;
  float val = myCurve.Evaluate(t);
  transform.localScale = Vector.one * val; //or do whatever you want with the curve value
}
```

Comment: Ahhh didn't think about exposing it to the editor. Thanks a lot, man. Exactly what I was looking for.